# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::Search()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un formulario en el que se introduce el nombre de un usuario para mostrar sus datos en una vista nueva.

[image: Buscar]

El controlador está de la siguiente manera:

```
public function veruser(Request $request){
   $user = App\User::Search($request->name)->first();
    return view('admin.veruser', compact('user'));
 }
```

Lo he intentado de varias maneras, pero me siguen saliendo errores en la vista al querer mostrar los datos del usuario que se quiere buscar.

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::Search()

Comment: Diferentes errores, dependiendo los cambios que haga, en este caso: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\User::Search() .
He visto que a varios le funciona el Search().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo encontré que puedes usar los métodos **`search`** bajo las siguientes condiciones:

- A nivel de las colecciones para filtrar los valores

El cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
$collection = collect([2, 4, 6, 8]);

$collection->search(4);
```

- A nivel de *Laravel Scout* el cual es un driver que se tiene que instalar **(si esta es la opción deseada, entonces verifica que lo tienes instalado)**

El cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
$orders = App\Order::search('Star Trek')->get();
```

**Opción propuesta**

Entonces para este caso si buscas filtrar por el nombre igual te conviene mas construir tu consulta así:

```
$name = $request->name;
$user = App\User::whereName($name)->first();
```

- Asignamos el valor que recibimos por el **`$request`** a una propiedad
- Hacemos uso del método **`where`** componiendo su nombre con el de la columna por la cual deseamos filtrar
- A dicho método le pasamos como argumento la propiedad que guarda el valor dle **`$request`**
- Terminamos la consulta encadenando el método **`first()`** para no obtener toda una colección sino solo los valores asociados a dicho registro

**Referencias**

- [Laravel scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout#introduction)
- [search collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-search)